# How to change text color when button pressed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with color change on button pressed , i made the bool condition and every thing is good but the color of the text not changing ?

my code :

```
    TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                pressed = !pressed;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              height: 60,
              width: 340,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'Suivant',
                style: pressed
                    ? TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)
                    : TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Code is fine. Tested it with a new project and it worked perfectly. Your error is somewhere else in your code

Comment: Where is your pressed variable located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is working fine for me. I can only guess what's the mistake.

Maybe your `pressed` variable is declared inside the `build()` method and not inside the `State` class.

> Try to move the declaration to class level and it should work fine

Comment: i have another question please. i have two button and i want the user can select on button how  i can do this ?

Comment: Introduce a second variable

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine.You are just the first pressed variable initial false.That's working fine.

Try check this Code:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
const Home({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

@override
_HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
bool pressed = false;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child:TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              pressed = !pressed;
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            height: 60,
            width: 340,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              'Suivant',
               style: pressed
                  ? TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)
                  : TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```